# How to not expand in autocmd?

Tags: vim

I have the following autocmd to define a `log` abbreviation in vim:

```
autocmd FileType vim,filetype_vim     iabbrev <buffer> log 
\ call LogOutput('', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
```

And when I type in `log`, I want it to type in exactly that:

```
call LogOutput('', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('<sfile>')[9:]})
```

This is sent to a log function, and so the `<sflnum>` and `<sfile>` are determined by the wherever the log call is done.

However, when I enter in `log` [space] in vim, here is what it outputs:

```
call LogOutput('', "DEBUG", {'line': expand('<sflnum>'), 'func': expand('/Users/david/.vim/vimrc')[9:]})
```

So, it seems to **not** expand the `sflnum` (which is what I want, but it **does** expand the `sfile`. How can I make it such that the abbrev/autocmd never expands that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:h :autocmd`

> Note that special characters (e.g., "%", "") in the ":autocmd"
>   arguments are not expanded when the autocommand is defined.  These will be
>   expanded when the Event is recognized, and the {cmd} is executed.  The only
>   exception is that "`<sfile>`" is expanded when the autocmd is defined.

To stop unwanted expansion make use of `<lt>`, e.g. `"\<lt>sfile>"`